# Can I find out from what computer certain files were transfered from on a USB device?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a standard usb flash drive with files on it. Can I somehow learn anything about the computer that those files were transferred from?

USB flash drive files system is NTFS or FAT32 and the file types are quite different (jointly they allow the installation of a statistical software package)

(I hope this is the appropriate network. based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange) post, it seemed like my best guess)

Comment: What filesystem is the drive formatted with? What type of files are on the drive?

Comment: Lets say either Fat32 or NTFS; various different file types which allow to install a particular software on a computer

Comment: The file attributes that exist for FAT32 and NTFS are significantly different.  What type of information are you trying to learn about the computer exactly?

Comment: for example whether the owner of the computer could reasonable identified, i.e. if any information is transmitted like former file paths, or any unique number that identifies a given computer etc

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.
Long answer.. you might be able to pull this off with NTFS (certainly not with FAT32).

One possiblity depends on if the files copied carry a copy of the the original access control list (ACL) like they would using xcopy /o /x.  I believe that it can be forced with a [registry modification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders).

This wouldn't *necessarily* allow you to see what machine it came from per say but it will show you the user/group SIDs that had access to the files to include whoever created the file.  ***By default***, files contain [localmachine]/Administrators on the ACL list. [localmachine]/Administrators sid should be unique to the machine it came from.

You could in turn use this information to figure out what machine it came from.  NOT a guarantee as permissions can be removed from the file but if nobody messes with stuff it would work.. uhh.. I think :^P